# How to connect to a SOAP webservice using SoapClient with a client certificate?

Tags: php, ssl, soap, soap-client

I put together a local Soap server for testing purposes. I created a client certificate to connect to it.

When calling the service from SoapUI I can connect just fine but when using `SoapClient` I can't seem to get it working.

I tried opening the WSDL directly (without the SoapClient) to see if the connection would work and it did but when using the exact same stream context as option for the constructor it produces a SoapFault exception: "Could not connect to host".

This is my code, can anyone see what's wrong with it? Thanks!

```
<?php

$context = stream_context_create(
    [
        'ssl' => [
            'local_cert' => __DIR__ . '/client.crt',
            'local_pk' => __DIR__ . '/client.key',
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => false,
        ]
    ]
);

$url = 'https://localhost:4430?WSDL';

echo "From file_get_contents: ".(file_get_contents($url, false, $context)).PHP_EOL;

echo "== Making the call ==".PHP_EOL;

try {
    $client = new SoapClient($url,
        [
            'stream_context' => $context,
        ]);

    echo "From ws call: ".$argv[1] . ' + ' . $argv[2] . ' = ' . $client->Add([
            'intA' => $argv[1],
            'intB' => $argv[2],
        ])->AddResult;
} catch (SoapFault $soapFault) {
    echo $soapFault->getMessage();
}

echo PHP_EOL;
```

This is the output I get:

```
From file_get_contents: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions name="Calculator"
             xmlns = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
             targetNamespace="urn:Calculator"
             xmlns:tns="urn:Calculator"
             xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
    <message name="addRequest">
        <part name="a" type="xsd:int"/>
        <part name="b" type="xsd:int"/>
    </message>
    <message name="addResponse">
        <part name="result" type="xsd:int"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="AddPort">
        <operation name="add">
            <input message="tns:addRequest"/>
            <output message="tns:addResponse"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="AddBinding" type="tns:AddPort">
        <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="add">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:CalculatorAction"/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:Calculator" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:Calculator" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="WSDLService">
        <documentation>Returns a greeting string.</documentation>
        <port name="AddPort" binding="tns:AddBinding">
            <soap:address location="https://localhost:4430/calculator_server.php?wsdl"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
== Making the call ==
Could not connect to host
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So apparently the code wasn't the problem but the SOAP cache. As soon as I disabled it using `ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", 0);` everything started working.